# Nitrous.io:moving rails app to mysql

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, nitrousio

I need to move my app from sqlite to mysql. I followed that guide

http://help.nitrous.io/mysql/

installed mysql, here is my yaml file

```
developement:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: dev-db
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

test:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: test-db
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: prod-db
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

When I try to do  `rake db:create` I get this error

> Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket
>   '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
>   Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"mysql2", "encoding"=>"utf8",
>   "database"=>"test-db", "pool"=>5, "timeout"=>5000}, charset: utf8,
>   collation: utf8_unicode_ci
>   (if you set the charset manually, make sure you have a matching
>   collation)

What do I need to do?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a socket to database.yml

Get the socket:

```
mysqladmin variables | grep socket
```

Which gives me on my system (OSX):

```
socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
```

and on Linux:

```
socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

Answer (score 0):

Something similar happened to me, and I just changed the default password with

```
mysqladmin -u root password newpassword
```